# Why does writing to a label break the resize of the UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

If I do no wire to the text field then the resize of the UIImageView works. If I write to the text area then the resize fails. I have no idea why the write to the text are would adversely affect the resize of the UIImageView.

```
@interface rjhccViewController ()

@end

@implementation rjhccViewController

-(IBAction)myButtonPress{

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p.png"];
[testcontainer setImage:img];
[testcontainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,50.0, 50.0)];
[self labelHeight:img];
}

-(void)labelHeight: (UIImage *) myimage{
//self.heightS.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)myimage.size.height];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[self setHeightS:nil];

[super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Comment: rjhccViewController, seriously?

Comment: well thanks for helping someone trying to learn. comments like that are so appreciated. Xcode asked for a prefix and set up the files that way.

Comment: what do you mean by saying that the resize did not work? what is `testContainer`? is that all of your code?

Comment: @BostonMacOSX When it comes to prefixes, at least, by the convention I've always known, they're generally all upper-case and from two to three characters in length. It's an issue that's nothing to do with your question, but it's still a good thing to know.

Comment: The name should be significative, you could call it something like ContainerViewController or something like this.Not to upset you, just to let you know the convention.

Comment: So here is what happens. testcontainer is a UIImage View. When I DO NOT write the text area called heightS the image on a button click will jump from 200px square to 50px square in the top left corner.  If I write the height to the text area the button will load the image into the UIView write its height to the text area and then NOT resize the image as it did before.

Comment: Ok, instead of getting distracted by your naming convention, can you provide more details of when/how you are attempting to resize this view? I see that your label height setter has code commented out on it. More details are needed to further address this!

Comment: It is commented out because when commented out the resizing works...when it is not commented out then it fails.

Comment: can you show the log NSLog("frame is = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(testcontainer.frame)); in labelHeight method after and before uncommenting self.heightS.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)myimage.size.height];